# Baking normal map

Tags: normal-map

Trying to bake maps but all i got its a mix of it. Why not separated? Who knows?

[image]

Thats the result i must have 
[image]

Comment: Looks like the only problem here is transparency between the UV islands..which is the result of alpha channel present in the image. It's possible to preview it without the channel by toggling option in editor or eliminating alpha channel as It doesn't appear to be required by normal map.

Answer (score 1):

To bake from hi-poly to lo-poly without a cage, you need to increase the Ray Distance. 0.5 or 1 should be fine.

[image: increase ray distance]

Comment: It do not works. Not 1 not .0.5.

Comment: Then you might want to upload your .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and pasting the given URL into your question. Anyway, I'm still pretty sure that the Ray Distance is the problem. And maybe you want to give a more clearer description about what you mean by "separate".

Comment: I added the image which xplains 'separation'.

Comment: I wanted to upload. But it seems that my project is too big for that(-=